# jquery validate Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Aca lo pruebo y funciona bien.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var validator = $( "#form-crear" ).validate();
  validator.form();
  console.log(validator);
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="crear_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-2">Nombre: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crear_nombre" name="crear_nombre">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</form>
```

Pero si lo intento en mi sistema me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: error]

Y compruebo que este llamando a la librería, correctamente en la cabecera:
[image: error]

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: ¿En dónde colocas el el script de `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: Probá llamar a las 3 librerias al comienzo del  HTML. Es decir, que las 3 llamadas sean lo primero que hagas.

Comment: Como dice @ZottoSL pon las tres librerías al principio del todo, en el `head` y también usa las rutas completas, por ejemplo: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js`